# Опциональные параметры в js?

Tags: javascript

Мне требуется написать функцию на js.
У этой функции должны быть опциональные аргументы, делаю так

```
const myFunc = (a, b) => {...}
```

Хочу реализовать следующую логику: функция универсальна, если в нее передают аргументы - использую их, если не передают, то вычисляю во время выполнения.

Но, возникла проблема, что если пытаюсь вызвать функцию ничего в нее не передавая, myFunc(), то вижу сообщение об ошибке, что не хватает параметров.
А если переделываю в

```
const myFunc = ({a, b}) => {...}
```

то вижу ошибку, что не хватает одного аргумента, как это можно разрешить?

p.s. Если говорить языком аналогий с java, то как перегрузить метод?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const myFunc = (...args) => {
  if (args.length == 0) {
    args[0] = "no ";
    args[1] = "parameters";
  }
  
  return args[0] + args[1]; 
};

console.log(myFunc(1, 2));
console.log(myFunc());
```

---

Возможно, Вам больше понравятся вычисляемые по умолчанию параметры:

```js
var i = 0, j = 0;
function calculateA() {
  console.log("calculateA");
  return ++i;
}
function calculateB() {
  console.log("calculateB");
  return (j += 100);
}

const myFunc = (a = calculateA(), b = calculateB()) => {
  return a + b; 
};

console.log(myFunc());
console.log(myFunc(1, 2));
console.log(myFunc(1));
console.log(myFunc());
```